# After installing the LAMMPS software, an error occurs when invoking it using the lmp command in the Command Prompt (cmd)

Tags: python, lammps

The error messages are

[image]

I have tried different versions of LAMMPS, but the above error message persists. Could you please advise on how to resolve this? I encountered the same error when trying to invoke LAMMPS in Python. Therefore, I need to address the installation issue with LAMMPS from the ground up.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in LAMMPS where it's trying to parse its version number wrong. You could patch the `get_version_number` function mentioned in the traceback to e.g. always return `0`.